# Add translation at each animation cycle loop in Unity

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a running animation. It already contains root animation. At every loop, it jumps to starting position.

**What is the best way to add a translation every time the animation loops?**

Comment: I would just move away from root motion entirely. You'd have to wait for the end of the loop, then teleport the player forward so that it lined up with the next frame of the root motion teleporting them backward....Doesn't seem worth it to me.

Comment: We need to obtain pretty accurate footplants. This is relatively harder to do by "injecting" root motion afterwards. So my main concern is to know how could I detect the clip is looping and how to add a translation from inside a script (or with the GUI).

Comment: Lets see... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1119151/how-to-detect-when-animator-loops.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html